# LF a PHP function to create a new product or a variation of an existing one in WooCommerce based on product name

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Before I start, note that I am a junior developer and this is technically my first big assignment.

Context: A parent company provides over 15k products. Child company selects a certain amount of those 15k to sell on their own site. Various products have the same product name but differ in size, color etc.

The function I'm trying to make checks the chosen products for duplicate product names and just imports or creates these if none are found. If it does find a duplicate product name it creates a variation of said product while making a new one aswell.

So in short: Looking for PHP function to either create a parent product or a parent product + a variation when products of the same name are found.

Below is the code I've got so far, I'm aware fnmatch probably won't work. (It's a fragment of an API.php file)

Thanks in advance!

```
                $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
                    if($product_name->fnmatch("productname" $string)){ 
                    function create_product_variation( $product_id, $variation_data ){
                        // Get the Variable product object (parent)
                        $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
                                $variation_post = array(
                                'post_title'  => $product->get_name(),
                                'post_name'   => 'product-'.$product_id.'-variation',
                                'post_status' => 'publish',
                                'post_parent' => $product_id,
                                'post_type'   => 'product_variation',
                                'guid'        => $product->get_permalink()
                            );
                        
                            // Creating the product variation
                            $variation_id = wp_insert_post( $variation_post );
                        
                            // Get an instance of the WC_Product_Variation object
                            $variation = new WC_Product_Variation( $variation_id );
                        
                            // Iterating through the variations attributes
                            foreach ($variation_data['attributes'] as $attribute => $term_name )
                            {
                                $taxonomy = 'pa_'.$attribute; // The attribute taxonomy
                        
                                // If taxonomy doesn't exists we create it
                                if( ! taxonomy_exists( $taxonomy ) ){
                                    register_taxonomy(
                                        $taxonomy,
                                       'product_variation',
                                        array(
                                            'hierarchical' => false,
                                            'label' => ucfirst( $attribute ),
                                            'query_var' => true,
                                            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => sanitize_title($attribute) ), // The base slug
                                        ),
                                    );
                                }
                        
                                // Check if the Term name exist and if not we create it.
                                if( ! term_exists( $term_name, $taxonomy ) )
                                    wp_insert_term( $term_name, $taxonomy ); // Create the term
                        
                                $term_slug = get_term_by('name', $term_name, $taxonomy )->slug; // Get the term slug
                        
                                // Get the post Terms names from the parent variable product.
                                $post_term_names =  wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, $taxonomy, array('fields' => 'names') );
                        
                                // Check if the post term exist and if not we set it in the parent variable product.
                                if( ! in_array( $term_name, $post_term_names ) )
                                    wp_set_post_terms( $product_id, $term_name, $taxonomy, true );
                        
                                // Set/save the attribute data in the product variation
                                update_post_meta( $variation_id, 'attribute_'.$taxonomy, $term_slug );
                            }
                        
                            ## Set/save all other data
                        
                            // SKU
                            if( ! empty( $variation_data['sku'] ) )
                                $variation->set_sku( $variation_data['sku'] );
                        
                            // Prices
                            if( empty( $variation_data['sale_price'] ) ){
                                $variation->set_price( $variation_data['regular_price'] );
                            } else {
                                $variation->set_price( $variation_data['sale_price'] );
                                $variation->set_sale_price( $variation_data['sale_price'] );
                            }
                            $variation->set_regular_price( $variation_data['regular_price'] );
                        
                            // Stock
                            if( ! empty($variation_data['stock_qty']) ){
                                $variation->set_stock_quantity( $variation_data['stock_qty'] );
                                $variation->set_manage_stock(true);
                                $variation->set_stock_status('');
                            } else {
                                $variation->set_manage_stock(false);
                            }
                        
                            $variation->set_weight(''); // weight (reseting)
                        
                            $variation->save(); // Save the data
                        }
                    else { //If product name does not have similarities a new one is made.
                        $post = array(
                            'post_author' => $user_id,
                            'post_content' => '',
                            'post_status' => "publish",
                            'post_title' => $product->part_num,
                            'post_parent' => '',
                            'post_type' => "product",
                            );
                            //Create post
                            $post_id = wp_insert_post( $post, $wp_error );
                                if($post_id){
                                    $attach_id = get_post_meta($product->parent_id, "_thumbnail_id", true);
                                    add_post_meta($post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $attach_id);
                                }
                                
                                wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, 'Races', 'product_cat' );
                                wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, 'simple', 'product_type');
                                
                                update_post_meta( $post_id, '_visibility', 'visible' );
                                update_post_meta( $post_id, '_stock_status', 'instock');
                                update_post_meta( $post_id, 'total_sales', '0');
                                update_post_meta( $post_id, '_downloadable', 'yes');
                                update_post_meta( $post_id, '_virtual', 'yes');
                                update_post_meta( $post_id, '_regular_price', "1" );
                                update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sale_price', "1" );
                                update_post_meta( $post_id, '_purchase_note', "" );
                                update_post_meta( $post_id, '_featured', "no" );
                                update_post_meta( $post_id, '_weight', "" );
                                update_post_meta( $post_id, '_length', "" );
                                update_post_meta( $post_id, '_width', "" );
                                update_post_meta( $post_id, '_height', "" );
                                update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sku', "");
                                update_post_meta( $post_id, '_product_attributes', array());
                                update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sale_price_dates_from', "" );
                                update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sale_price_dates_to', "" );
                                update_post_meta( $post_id, '_price', "1" );
                                update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sold_individually', "" );
                                update_post_meta( $post_id, '_manage_stock', "no" );
                                update_post_meta( $post_id, '_backorders', "no" );
                                update_post_meta( $post_id, '_stock', "" );
                            }
```